# Question about applying the Chain Rule with multiple variables

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $z = u(x,y)$ and $y = y(x)$ and $u(x,y(x))$ = 0.

What is the second derivative of the function $y(x)$?

I tried to use chain rule but I keep making mistakes

Answer (score 1):

We have two uses for the variable $y$ here: one to denote a coordinate in the plane, and another to denote a function of the first coordinate in the plane.

So just to clear up notation, let's write:

$$y: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto y(x).$$

Then denote the two coordinates for the plane as $x_1,x_2$ (i.e. $x=x_1,y=x_2$ where $y$ was being used as a coordinate).

This is still technically abuse of notation, but anyway starting from this we can write further:

$$z: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}, (x_1,x_2) \mapsto u(x_1,x_2)$$
$$u: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}, (x_1,x_2) \mapsto u(x_1,x_2)$$

Let's define the curve $C$ = $\{(x_1,y(x_1))\}$, determined by the points satisfying the equations $x_1=x_1$ and $x_2=y(x_1)$. Then the value of $u$ on this curve is 0.

We could also write $u$ as a function of one variable on this curve, specifically:

$$g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, x_1 \mapsto 0=u(x_1,y(x_1)).$$

Now let's try to solve this problem:

$$0=\frac{dg}{dx_1}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_2}|_C = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_2}\frac{dy}{dx_1}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx_1} = -(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_2})^{-1}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}$$

$$\implies \frac{d^2 y}{dx_1^2} = -\frac{d}{dx_1}\left[(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_2})^{-1}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}\right]$$

$$ =-{{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_2}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_1^2} - \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_1 x_2} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}}\over{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_2}^2}}.$$

In terms of the "variables" $x,y,z$, this can be written in sloppy shorthand as:

$$y''=\displaystyle{{\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x\partial y}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}- \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}}\over{\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}^2}}.$$

I always hated these problems; makes it too painfully clear how much abuse of notation is brushed under the rug. http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChainRule.aspx